# Http GET validation ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I currently have a search form, it has three fields (a dropdown and two `Nullable` date fields for a date range,) and all of which are required to perform a query, from what I've seen in the asp.net/mvc docs, to perform validation I'm required to create a `HttpGet` action method to build the model display the page and then use `HttpPost` to take that model and validate it (and whatever else it needs to after that, `RedirectToAction` etc and such).

Because this is a search query, I'd rather avoid using the http `POST` verb and stick with http `GET` verb instead, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to achieve this without either the error messages appearing on the initial request (remember `Nullable` date fields) or, if I put default values in, the `ModelState` being valid.

Here are my two methods:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        HomeIndexViewModel model = new HomeIndexViewModel()
        {
            SearchForm = new SearchFormViewModel()
            {
                GeoCounterDefinitions = geocounterservice.getAllDefinitions()
               .Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = x.CounterKey + " " + x.FriendlyDesc,
                    Value = x.CounterKey.ToString()
                })
            }
        };

        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(SearchFormViewModel search)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(new HomeIndexViewModel() {
                SearchForm = new SearchFormViewModel()
                {
                    CounterKey = search.CounterKey,
                    StartDate = search.StartDate,
                    EndDate = search.EndDate,
                    GeoCounterDefinitions = geocounterservice.getAllDefinitions()
                    .Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                    {
                        Text = x.CounterKey + " " + x.FriendlyDesc,
                        Value = x.CounterKey.ToString()
                    })
                }
            });
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Search");
    }
```

Comment: You could use your existing `Index()` method for the initial call and then have a (say) `[HttpGet]public ActionResult Search(SearchFormViewModel search) { ... }` method with both methods returning the save view with `@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", yourController, FormMethod.Get))`

Answer (score 1):

One way is to add a non-nullable property to `SearchFormViewModel` in order to detect if it's a form submit or not.

```
public class SearchFormViewModel 
{
     public bool IsSubmit {get; set;} 
}
```

in your form with `FormMethod.Get`

```
Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IsSubmit, true) ;
```

And then you can put both task (search display and actual search) in the same action :

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(SearchFormViewModel search)
{
    if (search.IsSubmit) { 
       return ActualSearch(search) ; 
    }

    // Display search page

    HomeIndexViewModel model = new HomeIndexViewModel()
    {
        SearchForm = new SearchFormViewModel()
        {
            GeoCounterDefinitions = geocounterservice.getAllDefinitions()
           .Select(x => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = x.CounterKey + " " + x.FriendlyDesc,
                Value = x.CounterKey.ToString()
            })
        }
    };

    return View(model);
}

private ActionResult ActualSearch(SearchFormViewModel search)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(new HomeIndexViewModel() {
            SearchForm = new SearchFormViewModel()
            {
                CounterKey = search.CounterKey,
                StartDate = search.StartDate,
                EndDate = search.EndDate,
                GeoCounterDefinitions = geocounterservice.getAllDefinitions()
                .Select(x => new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Text = x.CounterKey + " " + x.FriendlyDesc,
                    Value = x.CounterKey.ToString()
                })
            }
        });
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Search");
}
```